# Grub2 icons question

Tags: grub2, icons

Every time grub updates, due to normal updates, I lose some icons on the grub menu. I have to manually edit the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file and add '--class ubuntu' (or whatever) to lines that no longer have a '--class' entry and hence display no icon.

Where, exactly, does grub get the instruction to write a '--class' entry into the grub.cfg file ? I have looked at templates but can't see anything obvious.

I have read a few online grub guides but I'm finding it heavy going so thought I would ask for help !

(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who is interested, I have figured this out. The folder to look in is

```
/etc/grub.d/
```

There are a collection of files in here that are the templates for the generation of the file

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The files I am interested in are

```
10_linux*
30_uefi-firmware*
```

The 10_linux file is for linux operating system entries, the 30_uefi-firmware file is for the eufi setup entry.

To generate an icon for the submenu entry, I edited the corresponding line. The original line was this

```
echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {"
```

I added the CLASS option so that it now looks like this

```
echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {"
```

To add an icon for the System Setup entry i.e. the uefi settings (bios) I edited 30_uefi-firmware

I added a class entry, immediately after the export entries

```
CLASS="--class recovery"
```

and I added the CLASS option in the menuentry line

```
menuentry '$LABEL' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware'
```

The class entry has to match an icon that is in the themes icon folder.

```
/boot/grub/themes/<theme name>/icons
```

I have used the 'recovery' class/icon, which shows a toolbox icon. I will look for something a little more suitable when I get a moment, place the icon in the icons folder and change the class entry accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer mentioned you were searching for a better UEFI icon.

Here is [the icon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiVwdOfhpDcAhV1OX0KHVfrA98QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tenforums.com%2Ftutorials%2F5831-boot-uefi-firmware-settings-inside-windows-10-a.html&psig=AOvVaw2pV3kr-EPXxGjkEzo4yc8D&ust=1531158018203836) I'm using for my grub UEFI system setup option:

[image]

Here is another icon on [the net](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_vMqghZDcAhUUOn0KHQtTAYUQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zdnet.com%2Farticle%2Fuefi-boot-with-kororafedora-and-mintubuntu-hands-on%2F&psig=AOvVaw28fSire33WMtBqIgcgWg-1&ust=1531157688431882):

[image]

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply. It was just on 4 years ago that I was looking into this, I actually dont bother with grub themes at all now, I use the hidden countdown option with astandard text grub menu underneath. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora users, this will be helpful in implementing the fix above: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/cg3wl4/i_cant_find_menuentries_of_my_fedora_30_install/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you add the details from the link to your answer as try not to use link only answers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this fully automated is to make a script that makes regex replacements in your auto-generated `grub.cfg` to add the `--class`es you want. And then modifying `grub-mkconfig` (`/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` in Ubuntu derivatives) to run it at the end.

I use this idea on [Matter](https://github.com/mateosss/matter), a grub theme/tool that you may like (shameless plug).

Based on that, you could do it manually in python for example, [this function](https://github.com/mateosss/matter/blob/aa9c6dec8538f15864da724f26c6133df30d2508/matter.py#L441) (note the regex) returns a list of matches with each containing the name of your entry, that you can later iterate over to construct your `grub.cfg` replacement with correct `--class`es (example implementation [here](https://github.com/mateosss/matter/blob/aa9c6dec8538f15864da724f26c6133df30d2508/matter.py#L545)).

```py
def get_entry_names(grub_cfg):
    "Gets the entry names from grub.cfg contents"
    pattern = (
        r"(?P<head>(?:submenu|menuentry) ?)"  # menuentry or submenu
        r"(?:\"|')"  # " or '
        r"(?P<entryname>[^\"']*)"  # capture the entry name (without quotes)
        r"(?:\"|')"  # " or '
        r"(?P<tail>[^\{]*\{)"  # The rest of the entry header until a { is found
    )
    matchiter = re.finditer(pattern, grub_cfg)
    matches = list(matchiter)
    return matches
```